# after jQuery upgrade, uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: h3

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a new version of the website, and am now finding an issue with my javascript code that isn't being handled nicely.

What I have been doing in the past is

```
$('#lb_outer_title :h3').html(title);
```

which changed the text of the title attribute for my lightbox. This worked fine in jQuery 1.3.2, but on the new version (which is using jQuery 1.4.2) I get the error:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: h3
```

In the new version I can change the code to the following and it works, but this can't be the optimal solution:

```
$('#lb_outer_title').html('<h3>'+ title + '</h3>');
```

I've tried the using :first selector in my new version, but that doesn't work as desired either.

Here is the html that I'm working with (note: I can't add class or id to the h3 tag):

```
 <div id="lb_outer_title">
   <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Though the answers below correct the issue..if you title had special characters you may want them encoded, in which case you should weight `.html()` with `.text()`, depending on what you're sticking in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
$('#lb_outer_title :h3').html(title);
```

That colon before the `h3` should be dropped. jQuery 1.4 has a stricter selector engine and that's why it's reporting your error (since you're using a pseudo-class prefix on an element selector), while jQuery 1.3 merely silently parses the colon away.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#lb_outer_title h3').html(title);
```

Not sure what that colon was doing in there...  It is not a valid selector.  `:` is used for psuedo-classes, but you simply want an element.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `:` like this:

```
$('#lb_outer_title h3').html(title);
```

The colon prefix, `:`, is used for various [pseudo selectors](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=:), you just want `h3`, the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/).